# readfile() returns empty file while trying to force download

Tags: php, readfile, dwg

I'm trying to force download of `.dwg` files with the following code:

```
$filename = $_GET['f'];
$upload_path = wp_upload_dir();
$src = $upload_path['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;

header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$filename}\"");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($src);
die();
```

The path to the file is correct, but it only returns a file that is **6 byte** and that is not possible to open. It should be **754 bytes**. Anyone who can help me out here?

```
//Example file
$src = "/var/www/wp/wp-content/uploads/Glasparti-modell-Silence.dwg";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by the following in .htaccess instead:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(dwg)$" >
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header add Content-Disposition "attachment"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the `Content-length` header :

```
$size = filesize($src);
header("Content-length: $size");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried that with no different result. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use `.dwg` file Content-Type:

- application/acad
- application/x-acad
- application/autocad_dwg
- image/x-dwg, application/dwg
- application/x-dwg
- application/x-autocad
- image/vnd.dwg
- drawing/dwg

---

```
header("Content-type: 'application/pdf'");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
```

Can you try this,

```
<?php
    $file = '';// file path here 

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }else{
                  echo "File not found";
          }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried all of those with no better result. Any other idea?

Comment: Updated my post above!

Comment: Can you check the file permissions.

Comment: Check you `http://domainanme/filenameurl` in your browser and find you can able to download the same agaian. If possible check apache error log.

Comment: This works `http://www.domain.se/wp/wp-content/uploads/Glasparti-modell-Silence.dwg`. I don't have access to the apache error log on this server.

Comment: I have added two content type headers in my code. Please add this and check.

Comment: I tried to change to both content types you added with the same result as before.

Comment: I have added the download code, can you check. Or change the another file location try.

Comment: `flush();` causing "Page is not available" in Chrome. Without `flush();`, same result as before. `file_exists();` indicates that the path is correct because the file is found.

Comment: Did you tried with another file or you can able to download the from browser

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
    $name = $_GET['f'];
    $url = './files/'.$name;
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$name");
    readfile($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it !!

```
/**
 * file download in MVC
 * 
 * @author VECTOR Ann <ann@vector.cool>
 * @since 1.0.1
 * 
 * @param string $file          提供下載的檔案絕對路徑
 * @param string $download_name 下載的檔名
 * @return void
 */
function v_file_download($file,$download_name=''):void
{   
    if (is_file($file)) {
        if($download_name=='')$download_name = date('Y_m_d',time()).".zip";
        header_remove(); 
        ob_end_clean();
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($download_name));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        ob_end_flush();
        exit;
    }
}
```